# Pandas replace not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe res and the following code is not working for a big dataset. But is working for small data. What has to be done to make working?

```
res['Em'].replace(0,"Zero")
res = res.replace(True, pd.Series(res.columns, res.columns))
res = res.replace(False, "F")
```

Data Looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample?

Comment: sample data????

Comment: Yes, but in my opinion problem should be in data, if not working in large df

Comment: data is same as small df. Number of rows are more..that is the only difference.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that I can copy paste into a terminal, run, and understand what your problem is instead of showing me "code that doesn't work". Not helpful, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
res = res.replace([False], ["F"])
```

Comment: can you provide a sample

Answer (score 0):

I myself found the issue. I replaced

```
res['Em'].replace(0,"Zero")
res = res.replace(True, pd.Series(res.columns, res.columns))
res = res.replace(False, "F")
```

with

```
res['Em'] = res['Em'].replace('0',"Zero")
res = res.replace('True', pd.Series(res.columns, res.columns))
res = res.replace('False', "F")
```